# React hooks how search array child array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a json file like this

```
{"id": 1,
   "categoryName": "Download",
   "children": [
      {  "id": 3,
         "name": "name",
         "text": "text"
      }
   ]
}
```

and I have input for search. I can search onChange categoryname like this but I want search children names. How can I do this?

```
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
    const handleChange = event => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const results = data.filter(item =>
            item.categoryName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
        );
        setSearchResults(results);

    }, [searchTerm]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently You filtering by category name in line:

```
   item.categoryName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
```

You need to filter **not by categoryName** (case sensitive here)
and focus on **children.name** like this:

```
   item.children[0].name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
```

But this solutions will work only if children **array** have one **object**.

For including every objects - You need to iterate thought this array.

```
let results = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.children.length; i++) {
   oneChild = data.filter(item =>
       item.children[i].name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
   )
   results.push(oneChild)
}
```

---

After experimenting in sandbox - ii got this function, which filter in subelements of element, which are 2 nested levels

```
const results = data.map((element) => {
  return {
    ...element,
    subElements: element.children.filter((subElement) =>
      subElement.name.includes(searchTerm)
    )
  };
});
```

---

And finally that solution should filter:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let filteredArray = data
      .filter((element) =>
        element.children.some((subElement) =>
          subElement.name.includes(searchTerm)
        )
      )
      .map((element) => {
        let newElt = Object.assign({}, element); // copies element
        newElt.subElements = newElt.children.filter((subElement) =>
          subElement.name.includes(searchTerm)
        );
        return newElt;
      });

    setSearchResults(filteredArray);
  }, [searchTerm]);
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, it's an element of array. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can You try with that - item.children[0].name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) and also reproduce code in sandbox?

Comment: Thanks :) Here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-microservice-s8h5s

Comment: @okh let's check the last useEffect at edited question

Comment: Sorry, no errors but it doesn't work right :(

Comment: You need also change in ~52 line mapping . There is mapping thoughts searchResults instead data

Comment: I did not quite get it

Comment: @okh 
I prepared sandbox for You:
https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-shape-4il6w
It's working in initial form - i don't know which precise behaviour You need to accomplish.

Comment: For now - when one of child in array is the same as searchTerm, then display all data with subelements. For more precise solution i suggest UX analyse first, before coding.